# Upload App Inventor 2 to Google App Engine, Found more than 100 URLMap entries in application configuration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app-inventor

I'm building and uploading App Inventor 2 to our Google App Engine account. I'm following the instructions found here: [How to build App Inventor from the MIT sources](https://docs.google.com/a/bytedept.com/document/pub?id=1Xc9yt02x3BRoq5m1PJHBr81OOv69rEBy8LVG_84j9jc#h.b70u04nuv2sm).

Everything works fine until I try to upload to GAE. It builds and I'm able to run it on my local machine. The upload fails with the following...

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=com-bytedept-app-inventor-2&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Error when loading application configuration:
Found more than 100 URLMap entries in application configuration

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL:     https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=com-bytedept-app-inventor-2&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Error when loading application configuration:
Found more than 100 URLMap entries in application configuration

Please see the logs [/var/folders/qc/4l37zs2547v0jt05vwkjr_lc0000gp/T/appcfg9183580475283654947.log] for further information.
```

I've seen other questions referencing "Found more than 100 URLMap entries in application configuration" but I didn't see how their responses apply to this situation.

I'm using Java 1.7.0_51, and local App Engine Java SDK 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in the GAE 1.9.1 scripts. I downgraded to version 1.8.9 at it worked without a hitch.